# Помогите разобраться с решением задачи Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

> Условие:
>
> Дан текст на русском языке. Посчитайте, сколько раз встречается в тексте каждое слово.

Слово — это последовательность русских букв. Кроме слов, в тексте могут присутствовать пробелы и знаки препинания (`«,», «.», «!», «?», «:» и «;»`). Других символов в тексте нет.

Слова необходимо сравнивать с точностью до регистра. То есть «Привет» и «привет» — это одно и то же слово, а вот «рыба», «рыбы» и «рыбу» — три разных.

---

> Ввод:
>
> В первой строчке задано одно целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000) — количество строк в тексте. В следующих N строках приведён сам русский текст. Текст состоит из русских букв, пробелов и знаков препинания: «,», «.», «!», «?», «:» и «;». Длина текста не превышает 100 000 символов.

---

> Вывод:
>   Выведите слова исходного текста, упорядоченные по убыванию количества их попаданий в текст. В случае, если два слова встречаются в тексте одинаковое количество раз, выведите их в лексикографическом порядке.

Каждое слово нужно вывести в отдельной строке. Первая буква слова должна быть заглавной (даже если она не была заглавной в исходном тексте), остальные — строчными.

Пример:

> Ввод:

```
2
Ехал Грека через реку. Видит Грека в реке рак.
Сунул Грека руку в реку, рак за руку Греку цап.
```

> Вывод:

```
Грека
В
Рак
Реку
Руку
Видит
Греку
Ехал
За
Реке
Сунул
Цап
Через
```

У меня даже получилось решить задачу, но не без помощи, мне подсказали использовать непонятную мне функцию:

```
words_dict = {}
sentences1 = [input().split() for i in range(int(input()))]
sentences = [j.strip('!?:;,.').capitalize() for i in sentences1 for j in i]
for i in sentences:
    words_dict[i] = words_dict[i] + 1 if i in words_dict else 1
for word, qwerty in sorted(words_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])): # вот тут непонятно key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])
    print(word.capitalize())
```

На строке 6 в конце мне не до конца понятно, как работает выделенная функция, а именно, что она делает.

P.S. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`words_dict.items()` - это список значений вашего словаря. Он имеет вид:

```
dict_items([('Ехал', 1), ('Грека', 3), ('Через', 1), ('Реку', 2), ('Видит', 1), ('В', 2), ('Реке', 1), ('Рак', 2), ('Сунул', 1), ('Руку', 2), ('За', 1), ('Греку', 1), ('Цап', 1)])
```

Зная это, можно дать пояснение к сортировке:

```
# Отсортированный words_dict.items(), 
# где сначала в обратном порядке производится сортировка по x[1], т.е. количеству,
# а потом - внутри секций в прямом порядке по x[0], т.е. по самим словам
sorted(words_dict.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

Параметр `key` в функции `sorted` указывает, по чём именно сортируется итерируемый объект.

---

Более простой пример: имея список кортежей `[(1, 2), (-2, 3), (5, -10)]`, можно с помощью `key` отсортировать его, например, по нулевому элементу:

```
# x - это сами элементы списка, а сортируем мы по x[0]
>>> sorted([(1, 2), (-2, 3), (5, -10)], key = lambda x: x[0]) 
[(-2, 3), (1, 2), (5, -10)]
```

Comment: Когда я писал более развёрнутый код, я использовал сортировку пузырьком(создавал 2 списка с ключами и значениями) и потом сортировал их этим самым пузырьком. Но я сортировал сначала по алфавиту, а потом - по цифрам, так как по условию задачи надо вывести слова по убыванию количества слов в тексте. А тут, как вы говорите, сначала идёт сортировка по числу, а потом - по алфавиту и если поменять порядок сортировки, то программа выдаст неверный ответ, так что не до конца понятно, как ведёт себя эта функция при вводе от 2-х параметров(x[1], x[0], -x[1]) и более.

Comment: И ещё я заметил: если я хочу сортировать строки по убыванию, то когда я добавляю минус(-x[0]), то выдаёт ошибку, из этого выходит ещё один вопрос: как отсортировать строки по убыванию?

Comment: @TAWER768 Не уверен, насколько это идейно правильное решение, но можно отсортировать всё по `lambda x: (x[1], x[0])`, т.е. в порядке возрастания, а потом развернуть результат с помощью `reversed()`

Comment: А всё же, почему в функции идёт сначала сортировка по числу, а потом - по алфавиту, а ответ всё равно является верным, может быть, сортировка по алфавиту тут делается относительно сортировки по количеству и позиции слов в словаре как-то зафиксировались по количеству, а сортировка по алфавиту вставляла значения между уже зафиксированными значениями в словаре?

Comment: @TAWER768, потому что мы сортируем список кортежей, состоящий из пар: `("слово", частота)` и по условиям задачи сначала мы сортируем `частоту` в убывающем порядке (частота - __второй__ элемент кортежа), а потом сортируем в алфавитном порядке по слову - __первому__ элементу кортежа

Answer (score 2):

Лямбда функция - это вариант *безымянной* функции, состоящей из *одного выражения / команды*. Является синтаксическим сахаром и всегда может быть заменена обычной функцией (см. пример ниже). Часто применяется для сокращения кода, в тех местах где нужно передавать функцию в качестве параметра, например в качестве параметра `key` во встроенных функциях: `min()`, `max()`, `sorted()`, etc..

Пример замены обычной однокомандной функции лямбда функцией:

```
In [38]: def revers(s):
    ...:     return s[::-1]
    ...:

In [39]: revers("AbCdE")
Out[39]: 'EdCbA'

In [40]: (lambda x: x[::-1])("AbCdE")
Out[40]: 'EdCbA'
```

Конечно выглядит это ужасно и никто не применяет лямда функции таким образом.
Применение лямбда функций удобно и оправдано в том случае, когда на нужно передавать функцию в качестве аргумента другой функции или объекту класса.

Пример с сортировкой: - допустим надо надо отсортировать список кортежей сначала по второму элементу в убывающем порядке, а потом по первому элементу в возрастающем (как в вашем предыдущем вопросе):

```
In [42]: items = [(1,10), (1,20), (2,10), (2,20)]

In [43]: def f(x):
    ...:     return (-x[1], x[0])
    ...:

In [44]: sorted(items, key=f)
Out[44]: [(1, 20), (2, 20), (1, 10), (2, 10)]
```

того же эффекта можно добиться, не создавая именованной функции:

```
In [45]: sorted(items, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
Out[45]: [(1, 20), (2, 20), (1, 10), (2, 10)]
```

---

Ответ на вопрос из комментария:

> Как сортировать строки в обратном алфавитном порядке?

в том случае когда порядок сортировки всегда один - можно воспользоваться параметром [sorted(..., reverse=True)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
In [48]: sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
Out[48]:
[('грека', 3),
 ('руку', 2),
 ('в', 2),
 ('через', 1),
 ('цап', 1),
 ('сунул', 1),
 ('реку.', 1),
 ('реку,', 1),
 ('реке', 1),
 ('рак.', 1),
 ('рак', 1),
 ('за', 1),
 ('ехал', 1),
 ('греку', 1),
 ('видит', 1)]
```

Comment: А тут же мы мы сортируем сначала по убыванию по 2- ому элементу, а потом по 1-му элементу по возрастанию, а тут как-то получается, что окончательный ответ не сортирует список кортежей по 1-ому элементу по возрастанию.

Comment: @TAWER768, тут - это где? В предыдущем ответе вам сортировка соответсвовала заданию...

Comment: @TAWER768 сортировка по второму ключу выполняется среди категорий первого ключа. Например, при сортировке сначала по первому элементу, а потом по второму, можно визуально построить цепочку `[(1,2), (1,4), (1,3), (2, 1), (2,5), (1,-2)] ` -> `[[(1,2), (1,4), (1,3), (1,2)], [(2,1), (2,5)]]` -> `[[(1,2), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)], [(2,1), (2,5)]]` -> `[(1,2), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,5)]`

Comment: @MaxU разве сортировка по **развёрнутым** строкам сортирует их в обратном порядке? Мне казалось, она сортирует их в прямом порядке, но по **последнему** символу

Comment: @Евгений, да, со строками это я погорячился... сейчас уберу эту часть из ответа

Comment: @MaxU тут - это в примере с цифрами, который вы привели.

Comment: Думаю, вопрос об обратной сортировке строк вполне можно выделить в отдельный вопрос. Так будет правильнее

Comment: @TAWER768, все правильно сортирует: `sorted(items, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))` --> `[(1, 20), (2, 20), (1, 10), (2, 10)]` - сначала по второму элементу в убывающем, а потом по первому в возрастающем. Обратите внимание что в первых двух кортежах второй элемент - `20` и во всех случаях для одинаковых вторых элементов первые отсортированы в возрастающем порядке

Comment: @MaxU ну так, а там же по 1-ому элементу идут цифры 1, 2, 1, 2. Это же не по возрастанию, или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: @TAWER768 список сортируется по второму фрагменту элемента. Если есть такие элементы, где второй фрагмент совпадает - то они между собой сортируются по первому

Comment: @MaxU всё, я понял, больше не буду вас тревожить, спасибо большое!