# Замысловатая сортировка на питоне

Tags: python, сортировка

Пусть есть список объектов (или словарей):

```
obj_lst = [
    {"score": 90, "name": "рожь", "rank": 1}, 
    {"score": 90, "name": "овес", "rank": 1},
    {"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 3", "rank": 1}, 
    {"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 4", "rank": 1},
    {"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 3", "rank": 2}, 
    {"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 4", "rank": 2}
]
```

Хочу получить отсортированный список:

```
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 3", "rank": 1}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 4", "rank": 1}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 3", "rank": 2}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 4", "rank": 2}
{"score": 90, "name": "рожь", "rank": 1}, 
{"score": 90, "name": "овес", "rank": 1}
```

Применяю:

```
obj_lst_sorted = sorted(sorted(obj_lst , key=itemgetter("score"), reverse=True), key=itemgetter("rank"))
```

Получаю:

```
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 3", "rank": 1}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница мягк 4", "rank": 1}
{"score": 90, "name": "рожь", "rank": 1} 
{"score": 90, "name": "овес", "rank": 1}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 3", "rank": 2}
{"score": 95, "name": "пшеница тв 4", "rank": 2}
```

Comment: "хочу получить отсортированный список"... так он у вас только по "score" отсортирован... в списке словарей более поздняя сортировка перетрет предыдущие

Comment: Вот как сделать, чтоб не перетерала?

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1118680/211923)

Answer (score 3):

[Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), применяемый в `sorted()` - **стабильный** алгоритм сортировки, поэтому сначала отсортировав по ключу `"name"`, мы сортируем результат по ключу `"score"` и для одинаковых `"score"` - результат предыдущей сортировки сохранится:

```
res = sorted(
    sorted(obj_lst, key=itemgetter("name")),
    key=itemgetter("score"),
    reverse=True)
```

результат:

```
In [108]: res
Out[108]:
[{'score': 95, 'name': 'пшеница мягк 3', 'rank': 1},
 {'score': 95, 'name': 'пшеница мягк 4', 'rank': 1},
 {'score': 95, 'name': 'пшеница тв 3', 'rank': 2},
 {'score': 95, 'name': 'пшеница тв 4', 'rank': 2},
 {'score': 90, 'name': 'овес', 'rank': 1},
 {'score': 90, 'name': 'рожь', 'rank': 1}]
```

Comment: Попробовал. После сортировки по "name" нарушается сортировка по "id" - некоторые объекты с высоким id, оказываются в самом низу списка

Comment: @vitaly-post, приведите в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: @vitaly-post, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, чтобы внести изменения в вопрос)

Comment: Надо будет почитать по ссылке, странно, что это работает. Видимо, sorted возвращает какой-то хитрый объект, в котором записано, какие позиции были равно отсортированы, чтобы вторая сортировка их не трогала. По-другому не представляю как это может правильно работать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, тут нет никакой магии - Timsort, применяемый в `sorted()` - __стабильный алгоритм__ сортировки, поэтому сначала отсортировав по ключу `"name"`, мы сортируем результат по ключу `"score"` - для одинаковых `"score"` - результат предыдущей сортировки сохранится

Comment: @MaxU И всё-равно непонятно - ведь внещний `sorted` принимает на вход коллекцию, которую он сортирует уже по другому ключу. Откуда он знает, что то, что ему передали, не нужно трогать при совпадении какой-то информации, которую ему не передали? Или передали? Если только `sorted` видит, что ему на вход пришёл другой `sorted` и получает у него инфу о его сортировке. Как в `Linq` типа вся цепочка заранее анализируется и выполняется в том порядке, который интерпретатор посчитает правильным. )

Comment: @CrazyElf, `sorted()` - просто делает свою работу, сохраняя оригинальный порядок элементов для записей с одинаковым ключем (__стабильный__ алгоритм сортировки) - именно благодаря этому порядок предыдущей сортировки в каждой группе с одинаковым `"score"` не изменится

Comment: @MaxU Получается, что в цепочке sorted() первыми должны идти поля, которые нужно сортировать последними?

Comment: @vitaly-post, да, если мы используем вложенные `sorted()`

Answer (score 2):

Для числовых полей такая сортировка легко делается с использованием кортежа в качестве ключа сортировки:

```
obj_lst_sorted = sorted(obj_lst, key=lambda x: (-x["score"], x["rank"]))
```

Сначала думал, что поля будут символьные, с ними вот сложнее, пока лёгкого метода не нашёл. А для числовых полей ответ с кортежем уже давался тут неоднократно.

Comment: По ТЗ поле может быть любого типа, в том числе строкового.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1118709/211923  -  вложенные `sorted()` оказывается работают быстрее чем трюк с кортежем  ;)

Comment: @MaxU Таки надо отмечать дубликатом данный вопрос тогда, раз по ссылке всё хорошо разобрано :)

Comment: @vitaly-post сортировка по нескольким значениям может быть применена к спискам списков, но не к списку словарей, как-то это нелогично

Comment: @MaxU в вопросе иная сортировка, отличная от вопроса по ссыылке на дубль... эту вобще нельзя осуществить...

Comment: @Jack_oS, [ну почему же нельзя ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1256541/211923) PS дубликат убрал...

Comment: @MaxU потому, что ТСу нужна сортировка по score и rank

Comment: @Jack_oS, судя по результату, который ТС хочет получить, сортировка по "rank" не нужна)