# Сортировка списка по нескольким ключам

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список

Есть вот таткой список:

```
players = [
    ['alla', '4', '100'],
    ['gena', '6', '1000'], 
    ['gosha', '2', '90'], 
    ['rita', '2', '90'], 
    ['timofey', '4', '80']
]
```

где 'alla', '4', '100' - это имя, оценка и размер штрафа соответственно.

Его нужно отсортировать, но хитрым способом:

Сначала нужно по сортировать **по оценке по возрастанию**. То есть, если берем элемент ['gena', '6', '1000'], то обращаемся к '6'. При сортировке получается, что у нас пока что только один элемент подходит - ['gena', '6', '1000']. Из-за символа '6', он самый большой из всех.

Если, попадаются два элемента с одинаковыми **оценками**, например ['timofey', '4', '80'] и ['alla', '4', '100'], то мы должны их отсортировать по **размер штрафа**. И этот параметр нужно сортировать по **убыванию**. Тем меньше размер штрафа - тем лучше.
То есть, после элемента ['gena', '6', '1000'] пойдет ['timofey', '4', '80'], т.к. у него **размер штрафа** == '80', а потом уже будет идти ['alla', '4', '100'], т.к. у него **размер штрафа** == '100'. То есть уже по убыванию сортировка в этом случае.

А если у элементы списка **размер штрафа** одинаковы, то сортировать данные нужно по **имени**. Оно должно идти раньше **в алфавитном (лексикографическом) порядке**.

В итоге должно получиться вот так:

```
['gena', '6', '1000']  - на первом месте, так как самая большая из всех оценка, равная 6
['timofey', '4', '80'] - на втором месте, т.к. оценки у них меньше 6 и размер штрафа 80
['alla', '4', '100'] - на третьем месте, т.к. оценки у них меньше 6 и штрафа 100
['gosha', '2', '90'] - на четвертом месте, т.к. оценки и штрафы одинаковы, gosha идет ближе к началу алфавита.
['rita', '2', '90'] - на четвертом месте, т.к. оценки и штрафы одинаковы, rita идет после gosha, ближе к концу алфавита.
```

Я написал код, но он не сортирует по алфавиту:

```
def sort_players(players:list, len_array:int):
    players.sort(key=lambda arr: (arr[1], arr[2], arr[0]))
    while len_array > -1:
        print(players[len_array])
        len_array -= 1
```

ответ такой получается:

```
['gena', '6', '1000']
['timofey', '4', '80']
['alla', '4', '100']
['rita', '2', '90'] - должно быть последним
['gosha', '2', '90'] - должно быть предпоследним.
```

то есть Гошу и Риту нужно поменять местами. А как?

Comment: **по оценке по возрастанию** - судя по примерам, всё же по убыванию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно перевести оценку и штраф в целое и для "убывания" добавить минус:

```
players = [
    ['alla', '4', '100'],
    ['gena', '6', '1000'], 
    ['gosha', '2', '90'], 
    ['rita', '2', '90'], 
    ['timofey', '4', '80']
]

sorted_players = sorted(
    players, 
    key=lambda arr: (
        -int(arr[1]), 
        -int(arr[2]), 
        arr[0]
    )
)

print(*sorted_players, sep='\n')

['gena', '6', '1000']
['alla', '4', '100']
['timofey', '4', '80']
['gosha', '2', '90']
['rita', '2', '90']
```

Comment: [вложенные `sorted()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1118680/211923) часто работают быстрее чем сложные lambda-функции в ключах ;)

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Код слегка подправил. По поводу вложенных функций sorted - отдельная благодарность, не подозревал о такой возможности ). Век живи - век учись. Спасибо еще раз.