# Как отсортировать список кортежей по определенному элементу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, сортировка, tuple

В списке есть кортеж, в кортеже есть число по которому надо отсортировать кортежи в порядке возрастания.

```
a = [([3.0, 2.0], 0, 1.0), ([3.0, 2.0], 1, 1.0), ([4.0, 3.0], 1, 1.0), ([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83), ([3.5, 1.5], 0, 2.0), ([1.6666666666666667, 1.25], 0, 0.42), ([3.5, 1.0], 1, 2.5), ([5.0, 2.5], 1, 2.5), ([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83), ([2.0, 1.3333333333333333], 0, 0.67)]
```

Отсортировать надо по последнему числу. Должно получится так:

```
a = [([1.6666666666666667, 1.25], 0, 0.42),([2.0, 1.3333333333333333], 0, 0.67),([3.0, 2.0], 0, 1.0),([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83),([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83), ([3.0, 2.0], 1, 1.0), ([4.0, 3.0], 1, 1.0),  ([3.5, 1.5], 0, 2.0), ([3.5, 1.0], 1, 2.5), ([5.0, 2.5], 1, 2.5) ]
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278874/420098 если понадобится отсортировать по нескольким ключам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

результат:

```
[([1.6666666666666667, 1.25], 0, 0.42),
 ([2.0, 1.3333333333333333], 0, 0.67),
 ([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83),
 ([2.5, 1.6666666666666667], 0, 0.83),
 ([3.0, 2.0], 0, 1.0),
 ([3.0, 2.0], 1, 1.0),
 ([4.0, 3.0], 1, 1.0),
 ([3.5, 1.5], 0, 2.0),
 ([3.5, 1.0], 1, 2.5),
 ([5.0, 2.5], 1, 2.5)]
```